# d3js : Stacked Horizontal Bar : How to split categories into bars

Tags: d3.js

I am creating a simple horizontal stacked bar chart in d3js.
http://jsfiddle.net/NovasTaylor/1e2pn4jb/

```
var stack = d3.layout.stack();
```

I am an newbie and so based my code on an original (see comment in JSFiddle) that has only a single stacked bar. I want to break the display into multiple bars based on a categorical variable. In my data I call this variable "skill" with values values "Windows" and "Linux". I would be very grateful if someone could suggest a way to do this based on the data values.

I searched the web and StackOverflow and found few examples of horizontal stacks (but a few verticals...)

Thank you!
Tim

Answer (score 1):

The important thing is to **nest** the data by `level` before creating the `stack` layout. Then create an ordinal `yScale` using `skill` as the domain.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/94j0qmnv/2/

First create a `nest` function:

```
var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function (d) {
        return d[0].level;
});
```

and call it before creating the `stack` layout:

```
//Data
dataset = stack(nest.entries(dataset));
```

That will nest your data by each of the 3 skill levels (*Begin*, *Intermed*, *Adv*). Doing this means you'll need to add to your definition of `d3.layout.stack()` to specify how to extract values:

```
var stack = d3.layout.stack()
.values(function (d) {
    return d.values;
})
.x(function (d) {
    return d[0].x;
})
.y(function (d) {
    return d[0].y;
});
```

Then set up a yScale, to split the data into two bars based on the skill (*Windows* or *Linux*)

```
// Define the scale for the y (ordinal) domain
var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, 60], 1, 0)
    .domain(dataset.map(function (d) {
    return d[0].skill;
}));
```

Now all that is left is to change how the `x`, `y`, and `width` attributes are determined for each `rect` (and doing something equivalent with the `text` elements. In particular, to split each layer into the two rows (based on `skill` value), use the new `yScale`:

```
...
.append("rect")
...
.attr("y", function (d) {
  return (yScale(d[0].skill) + 40);
})
```